# How can i change language of page to arabic as i type in english in syncfusion Angular?

Tags: angular, editor, document, syncfusion

I am able to change the language of its menus and side bar into arabic using its buildin options. But i want to change the content of pages too into arabic as user starts typing the page. But somehow i am not able to access the right element which contains that text which needs to be updated...
Thanks :)

When i try to access the element i get wiered json object which i don't understand..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QLUT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdzA2.png)

```
export class DummyComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('documenteditor_default')
  public container: DocumentEditorContainerComponent;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onCreate():void {
    console.log(this.container.documentEditor.serialize());
    }

}
```

```
<ejs-documenteditorcontainer serviceUrl="https://ej2services.syncfusion.com/production/web-services/api/documenteditor/"
    height="100%" 
    (contentChange)="onCreate()"
    #documenteditor_default
    enableRtl = "true"
    locale="ar-AE"
    [enableToolbar]=true>
</ejs-documenteditorcontainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to change the language of its menus and side bar into arabic using its buildin options. But i want to change the content of pages too into arabic as user starts typing the page.​

The document editor supports multiple languages. You can import and edit documents in any language, and you can type in any language by choosing their keyboard language.

But somehow i am not able to access the right element which contains that text which needs to be updated

You can get the selected content as text using text API in selection module

[Documentation](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/document-editor/how-to/get-the-selected-content/#get-the-selected-content-as-plain-text)